# Find the Pattern in Symbols and Answer. What must be the answer and Why

Tags: pattern, visual, symbols

[image]

Try to find the solution. Which option or Block would fit in the Blank space and Why? What pattern do You observe in this Puzzle.

Comment: Just want to be absolutely sure, the bottom right one is a triangle, right? It looked just a little too rounded for me to not check.

Comment: Yes, It is A Triangle.

Answer (score 10):

The block that fits the blank space best is

> the fourth one

And the pattern observed is

> Each row and column contains only 2 identical symbols

---

> Here's an ascii drawing:
>  $\begin{array}{ccccc}\\▲&◆&?&?&←\\→&▲&⬟&?&→\\⬟&◆&→&⬟&←\\\rm O&←&■&\rm O&⬟\\▲&→&■&◆&▲\end{array}$
>
>  The only one that fits is
>  $\begin{array}{cc}\\◆&■\\&\rm O\end{array}$
>
>  Because it gives row 1 two ◆ and column 4 two O.

Proof the others don't work:

> The first block would put two ⬟ in row 2, and there are already two →
>  The second block would put two → in column 3, and there are already two ■
>  The third block would put two ⬟ in column 3, and there are already two ■
>  The fifth block doesn't give row one two of anything.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I posted this some time ago, but the I found a flaw in it, so I deleted. However, it migt help somebody else, so I decided to undelete it.</sup>

Let's look at:

> How many times each symbol appear two times in the same row or column?

So, let's analyze that:

> 1st column: Two triangles
>  2nd column: Two diamonds
>  3rd column: Two squares
>  4th column: ???
>  5th column: Two left arrows
>  
>  1st row: ???
>  2nd row: Two right arrows
>  3rd row: Two pentagons
>  4th row: Two circles
>  5th row: Two triangles

Now, what ***can't*** fill the spaces while mantaining this pattern?

> The 3rd and the 5th pictures won't produce any repeating symbol in the 1st row.
>  The 1st picture would make the 2nd row with two pairs of repeating symbols.
>  The 2nd picture would make the 3rd column with two pairs of repeating symbols.

This leaves us with only a single possibility:

> **The solution is the 4th picture.**

This fills the patterns with:

> 4th column: Two circles
>  1st row: Two diamonds

Comment: This looks like the same conclusion I came to; however, what's wrong with the 4th picture? It doesn't need to produce any repeating combinations because row 2 already has a repeating combination

Comment: @Tas That is what happens when people interrupts me many times for no good reason when I'm are trying to solve a puzzle, I end commiting silly mistakes. My bad. Now, although I got very close, you completed it first.

Comment: Truthfully I had the same problem. I found the answer, then when I was writing it all out I got confused and initially thought 1 was meant to be it and couldn't remember why I had discounted it, but eventually noticed the flaw with it again